# How to attach to a process as a debugger and query information?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to essentially write my own profiler which attaches to my process, freezes execution, inspects the state (current instruction pointer, some metadata, etc..) and write this information to a log. How do I get started with this? If I can get in and inspect this information and then resume execution, I can proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Debugger API in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679303%28VS.85%29.aspx). An overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679266%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

To get you going here is info on [how to attach to a running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).